# ActiveRecord Associations(has_one) - Access parent object

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  has_one: child
end


class Child < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent
end


childrens = Child.includes(:parent)

puts childrens.to_json
[{"id":1,"parent_id":1,"name":"Jack"},{"id":2,"parent_id":2,"name":"Oleg"}]
```

In this case, we can access parent object like this: child.parent

But it is not possible to access parent object in view.
Is there any way to include parent objects in each child?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `as_json` with the `include` option to get each child parent:

```
Child.includes(:parent).as_json(include: :parent)
```

For that you get a couple of queries. One for the children, the other one  for each children parents (IN clause):

```
Child Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "children".* FROM "children"
Parent Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "parents".* FROM "parents" WHERE "parents"."id" IN ($1, $2)  [["id", 1], ["id", 2]]
```

You can limit the columns you're retrieving from the database (with `select`) as well as each object in the JSON object (that doesn't apply a SQL filter).

Comment: Beat me too it :) For reference: [ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON#as_json](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of confusion which you made with `includes`. This will not include the objects, but prepares them in case they are needed.

Because you have an association between `Parent` and `Child`, you can already get the parents in view, but this will request the parent for every children hence you'll run in n+1 queries.

To put it in code:

```
Child.all.each { |c| c.parent }; nil
```

will trigger:

```
Parent Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "parents".* FROM "parents" WHERE "parents"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1   [["id", 4750516]]
Parent Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "parents".* FROM "parents" WHERE "parents"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1   [["id", 4772539]]
Parent Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "parents".* FROM "parents" WHERE "parents"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1   [["id", 4806512]]
```

What you do there with includes, will make it look like:

```
SELECT "children".* FROM "children"
Parent Load (3.3ms)  SELECT "parents".* FROM "parents" WHERE "parents"."id" IN (4750516, 4772539, 4806512)
```

So, if you want to use it in the view, you'll actually have something like `@childrens` so don't be afraid to iterate over and call `.parent`.

You can read more about eager loading [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)

Answer (score 0):

```
Child.includes(:parent).as_json(include: :parent)
```

This helped me!